# Jest: How to test prop that is an anonymous function?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component that loads another component, sending it an anonymous function as a prop:

```
export class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { activeTab: TAB_NAMES.NEEDS_REVIEW }
  }

  filterByNeedsReview() {
    const { filterByNeedsReviewFn } = this.props
    this.setState({ activeTab: TAB_NAMES.NEEDS_REVIEW })
    filterByNeedsReviewFn()
  }

 ...

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        ...
        ...
          <FilterTab
            active={this.state.activeTab === TAB_NAMES.NEEDS_REVIEW}
            name={TAB_NAMES.NEEDS_REVIEW}
            count={40}
            onClick={() => this.filterByNeedsReview()}
          />
          ...
        ...
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

I have this failing test:

```
  it('renders a filter tab with the right props for needs review', () => {
    const filterByNeedsReviewFn = jest.fn()
    expect(
      shallowRender({ filterByNeedsReviewFn })
        .find(FilterTab)
        .findWhere(node =>
          _.isMatch(node.props(), {
            active: true,
            name: 'Needs Review',
            count: 40,
            onClick: filterByNeedsReviewFn, //<-------------- THIS DOESN'T WORK
          })
        )
    ).toHaveLength(1)
  })
```

How would I test that `onClick` is the right thing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to check how internal event handlers look like. You might be interested in different things: if triggering event handler changes component as you expect(`.toMatchSnapshot()` is much better here instead of testing structure manually with `.toHaveLength`) and if callback you've passed through `props` is called when it should to(`.toHaveBeenCalled`). What if component is changed some day not to just call `.props.filterByNeedsReviewFn()` but also do some stuff like calling anything else? should your test fail just because there is named method passed somewhere inside? I believe it is not.

So I see your test to be

```
it('renders a filter tab with expected props after clicking', () => {
    const comp = shallowRender({});
    comp.find(FilterTab).simulate('click');
    expect(comp).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('calls callback passed after clicking on filter tab', () => {
    const filterByNeedsReviewFn = jest.fn()
    const comp = shallowRender({ filterByNeedsReviewFn });
    comp.find(FilterTab).simulate('click');
    // let's ensure callback has been called without any unexpected arguments
    expect(filterByNeedsReviewFn ).toHaveBeenCalledWith(); 
});
```

I don't think you actually needed this code but I wanted to illustrate how clear such approach could be. Your component have API: props callback it calls and render output. So we can skip testing internals without any pitfalls

Comment: hm thanks for this. i'm still a little unsure of how snapshot testing is beneficial when there are no explicit assertions? like sure if i update the internals of my component method `filterByNeedsReview()` one day, tests should reflect that, no? but with snapshot testing you just update the snapshot by taking the latest version of the rendered component and move on. i don't get how that tests anything?

Comment: snapshot testing is about "nothing has been changed after last time we checked". it's much more efficient while testing structure/value than manual checks are(and does not help while testing behavior/function's call). I do believe if `filterByNeedsReview` is changed but component behaves the same - it should not make your tests fail. also you may even input snapshot manually instead of relying on "if there is no snapshot yet let's assume we have valid input and save it as a snapshot"

Comment: @Edmund, sorry, forgot to mention you in comment above